# @Html.Action causing 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object' exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I'm getting a 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object' exception and the culprit is a @Html.Action inside my view. I just figure out why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My Controller

```
public class AsyncController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Jobs()
        {
            var jobViewModel = new JobViewModel("Junior Accountant", Sector.Accountancy, DateTime.Now, "Enterprise Banking");

            return View(jobViewModel);
        }

        public ActionResult MoreJobs(JobViewModel model)
        {
            var viewModel = new MiniJobsView(model);
            return PartialView("_Rand.cshtml", viewModel);
        }
    }
```

Jobs View

```
@model SampleAsyncPartialViews.ViewModels.JobViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Jobs";
}

<h2>@Model.Title</h2>
<h3>@Model.CompanyName</h3>
<h3>@Model.Sector</h3>
<h3>@Model.StartDate</h3>

@Html.Action("MoreJobs", Model);
```

_Rand Partial View

```
@model SampleAsyncPartialViews.ViewModels.MiniJobsView

<div>
    <h1>@Model.Title</h1>
</div>
```

JobViewModel

```
namespace SampleAsyncPartialViews.ViewModels
{
    public class JobViewModel
    {
        public JobViewModel(string title, Sector sector, DateTime startDate, string companyName)
        {
            Title = title;
            Sector = sector;
            StartDate = startDate;
            CompanyName = companyName;
        }

        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Sector Sector { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Sector 
    {
        Accountancy,
        IT,
        Marketing,
        Sales
    }
}
```

MiniJobsView

```
namespace SampleAsyncPartialViews.ViewModels
{
    public class MiniJobsView
    {
        public MiniJobsView(JobViewModel model)
        {
            Title = model.Title;
            StartDate = model.StartDate;
        }

        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I understand the exception, I just don't understand why @Html.Action would have to generate a new instance of JobViewModel, when i'm already passing the model.

Comment: There is no [`Action()` method that takes a model for a parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action(v=vs.118).aspx).  Why do you need to use Action()?

Comment: did you mean to use `@Html.RenderAction("MoreJobs", Model);` instead of `@Html.Action("MoreJobs", Model);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to render your partial view into your view. There is no overload for Html.Action that take your model as a parameter. 
The solution for doing what you want is to use Html.Partial methods like this :

```
@Html.Partial("MoreJobs", new MiniJobsView(Model))
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't bind model using `@Html.Action("MoreJobs", Model);` in your controller.

Try `@Html.Partial("MoreJobs", new MiniJobsView(Model))` what CodeNotFound Said.

Answer (score 0):

The `Html.Action` method wants the data like a *object* with *route values*.

```
// Correct:
@Html.Action("MoreJobs", new { model = Model});
// Wrong:
@Html.Action("MoreJobs", Model);
```